# Distance between two lat/lng-points (geography) on a plane

Tags: postgis

I use PostGIS with PostgreSQL to calculate the distance between two places, specified by a latitude and longitude coordinate. The outcome of 18.5 km is what I expect:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(epicenter, house_location)/1000 "distance_in_km"
FROM (
  SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(53.345, 6.672),4326)::geography(point,4326)         epicenter 
  ,      ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(53.2081669, 6.5759146),4326)::geography(point,4326) house_location
) x;
```

What I want to know is the distance between those two points, without considering the curve of the earth.

My use case: I have a location of an earthquake (epicentre) and a location of a house. I also know the depth of the earthquake, and with Pythagoras I calculate the distance between the house and the hypocenter.

These calculations are Euclidean, but the distance calculation is not. I've heard the difference is minimal, but I want to know for myself what the difference is, how I can calculate it?

I assume both places have the same distance to the earth's center (but if you know how to take that fact into the equation, I would be interested as well).

Comment: Nice question. Anyways, I would say the direct waves of an earthquake will move along the surface, so the distance including the curve will be right to measure wave speed or similar. For non-direct waves it's way more complicated ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate straight line distance from spherical distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214926/how-to-calculate-straight-line-distance-from-spherical-distance)

Comment: The difference is really small: `2×6371×sin(0,5×18,5÷6371) = 18,4999935` (Needed to change Angle Units of Gnome Calculator from Degrees to Radians `Calculator --> Preferences`)

Comment: How high is the plane?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make my question less broad... However, it has been answered below. I also think my question is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the euclidean distance as described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214939/87998).

In your case, you can directly calculate it in PostGIS like this:

```
SELECT 2*6371*sin(0.5*(ST_DISTANCE(epicenter, house_location)/1000)/6371) direct_distance_in_km
FROM (
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(53.345, 6.672),4326)::geography(point,4326) epicenter,
ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(53.2081669, 6.5759146),4326)::geography(point,4326) house_location
) x;

direct_distance_in_km
------------------
 18.4999935003692
(1 row)
```